# Django register view of many to many connection table in Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many, django-orm

I have a Django model, and two model classes with many to many relationships between them.

```
class A(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(B, related_name='a')

class B(models.Model):
   id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=10)
```

Inside the database, I know, ORM creates the connection table between database `A` and `B`: `A_B`

I would like to create an `Admin` class out of this connection table.

```
@admin.register(A_B)
class ConnectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
```

Is there a way to do it?

**P.S.**

---

I know that I could do the Inline field in the B admin or "normal" field in A admin class, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I've posted an answer, did it help? Did I miss something? Please let me know ;D

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to obtain the auto generated intermediary (`through`) model object, and it is the following, using your example:

```
A_B = A.a.through
```

You could also get it by `B` via the `related_name`:

```
A_B = B.a.through
```

So for your admin you should get `A_B` using one of the above methods and then write your code:

```
A_B = A.a.through
@admin.register(A_B)
class ConnectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
```